# Bound of the Absolute Value of a Random Walk

Tags: stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus, martingales

Let $W(n)$ be a simple random walk on $\mathbb{N}$ with $W(0) = w_0$. That is, $\mathbb{P}\left[W\left(n+1\right) = W(n)+1\right)] = 1/2$ and $\mathbb{P}\left[W\left(n+1\right) = W(n)-1\right)] = 1/2$ for all $n$.

Is it true that
$|W(n)| \leq |w_0| + \sqrt{n} $? If so , how do I show this?

Comment: No, it's not true. With probability $>0$ it happens that $W_k-W_{k-1}=1$ for all $k=1,\ldots,n$ and so $W_n = w_0+n$ with probability $>0$.

Comment: But isn't it that $|W_n-W_0| \leq |W_n - W_{n-1} + W_{n-1} -W_{n-2} +\cdots +W_1  - W_0| \leq |W(n) - W_0| \leq n$. And so, 
$|W(n) - W(0) +W(0)| \leq |W(n) - W(0)| + |W(0)| \leq n + |W(0)|$?

Comment: Sure, but $n > \sqrt{n}$. Therefore $|W_n| \leq n + |W_0|$ does not imply $|W_n| \leq \sqrt{n} + |W_0|$.

Comment: Yeah sorry for this question. I just found this to be claimed by some paper I am reading. And this also got me absolutely confused. Probably a typo of some sort.

Answer (score 0):

This is not true for any $n>1$. Suppose $w_0\geq0$. Then we have $P(|W(n)|>|w_0|+\sqrt{n})\geq P(W(n)>w_0+n)=(1/2)^n>0.$